# ValueError: Cannot query "": Must be "Group" instance

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-permissions

I create custom user and Group model inherit the `Abstract user model`and `auth Group model`.

But I create the staff member and give some permission the same error trigger.
then check the user permission the same error trigger.

Put some code or error .
How to figure out this error??
 `

```
(Pdb) user=request.user
(Pdb) user
<SimpleLazyObject: <User: Gaurav@gmail.com>>
(Pdb) user.groups.first()
<UserGroup: Test>
(Pdb) g1=user.groups.first()
(Pdb) g1.permissions.all()
<QuerySet [<Permission: auth | group | Can add group>, <Permission: auth | group | Can change group>, <Permission: auth | group | Can delete group>, <Permission: auth | group | Can view group>, <Permission: camera | CameraGroup | Can add CameraGroup>, <Permission: camera | CameraGroup | Can change CameraGroup>, <Permission: camera | CameraGroup | Can delete CameraGroup>, <Permission: camera | CameraGroup | Can view CameraGroup>]>
(Pdb) user.has_perm('view_cameragroup')
*** ValueError: Cannot query "Gaurav@gmail.com": Must be "Group" instance.`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter in `has_perm()` method seems incorrect. Parameter for checking permission made from app label, permission code and model name. For example your app name is *blog* and your model name is *Post*. If you want user have view permission then you can check it by `user.has_perm('blog.view_post')`.

You can get further guidance from django documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions

I hope this will help you :)